# sending logs to splunk between docker containers

Tags: java, docker, logging, splunk

I have an app that runs in a docker container (say A). The app includes a log4j2 yaml configuration file, which has an Http_Appender routing logs to http://host.docker.internal:8080/log ready to be received in a proxy in docker container B. These logs are then setup to be queued to a websocket server at localhost:8080.

How might I configure the proxy to not only output to a websocket but also to splunk enterprise, where queries for the app take in stuff like the proxy name in java

Comment: How is this question related to programming? It might be better suited for [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [sf].